# Первые шаги в Spring

Tags: java, spring

Создаю эти классы:

**Quoter:**

```
package quotes;

public interface Quoter {
    void sayQuote();
}
```

**TerminatorQuoter:**

```
package quotes;

public class TerminatorQuoter implements Quoter {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void sayQuote() {
        System.out.println("message = " + message);
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
    package quotes;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        context.getBean(TerminatorQuoter.class);
    }
}
```

**context.xml** располагается в папке `resources` и имеет следующее содержание:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="quotes.TerminatorQuoter" id="terminatorQuoter">
        <property name="message" value="I'll be back"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

На консоль выводится следующее:

```
окт 19, 2016 9:05:28 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2e5d6d97: startup date [Wed Oct 19 21:05:28 MSK 2016]; root of context hierarchy
окт 19, 2016 9:05:28 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [context.xml]
```

**Почему не распечаталось мое сообщение ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что нужно вызвать метод `sayQuote()`:

```
Quoter q = context.getBean(TerminatorQuoter.class);
q.sayQuote();
```

Comment: А ещё, мне кажется, правильнее было бы

`Quoter q = context.getBean("terminatorQuoter");`